# How to remove a div from the entire project?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I've got a project consisting of over 200 html files. There's a div repeated throughout most of these, looking like this:

```
<div class='foobar' id="abcdef123'></div>
```

I have found all uses of the class using the Find in Files function in Sublime Text 2 - now I want to remove them, i.e. completely delete any line containing that div (and its closing tag).

Is there an easy way to do it in Sublime Text 2?

EDIT: I have forgotten to mention that sometimes the div has additional classes and the ID is always different. How would I write a regexp to deal with that?

Comment: it is a find and replace of that line with an empty string

Comment: You can use regular expression find&replace, if they hame multiple classes.

Comment: you can hide this by css if you don't want to change each file

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal that's a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, open all 200 files and replace with the following regular expression.

```
<div class='foobar[^']*' id="[^']*"></div>
```

and replace it by nothing. I don't know Sublimetext2.

Comment: Thanks! The same regexp worked in Sublime. Didn't even have to open the files.